# What's the debugger for Perl?

Tags: perl, debugging

I came from PHP, and I used zenddebugger to debug PHP.

How can I debug Perl?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the built-in Perl debugger:

```
perldoc perldebug
```

Comment: so debugger is built in,don't need to install any extensions?

Comment: Correct; it's perl5db.pl in the base distribution. There are some installable debuggers as well.

Answer (score 6):

While [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141560/whats-the-debugger-for-perl/6141579#6141579) is optimal, using the strict and warning pragmas:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Will help you catch the majority of your errors if you aren't already using them.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my debugging tip recycled from perlmonks.

Let the debugger automatically stop program execution whenever a warning is issued from the Perl runtime system. So you can look at the context of the problem and investigate.

[This node is giving the motivation](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=702678) and [here it is in its final form](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=702691).

Answer (score 1):

In any way you choose, don't forget to add `Data::Dumper` to your debugging routines.

Comment: Why is that? What is the advantage? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

[Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/Devel-Peek-0.96/Peek.pm#) is a good data debugging tool.

Comment: That may well be, but how does it answer the question?